# How to find out root cause if dpkg command says package status half-configured

Tags: dpkg

I have a package (say kaupackage) installed on my ubuntu machine. 
Now I want to replace it with higher version.

I run command

```
dpkg -i -R -B -a --force-confold /tmp/kaupackage.deb
```

The dpkg log shows

```
2018-01-31 06:37:22 upgrade kaupackage:amd64 2.2.0.0.0.7707465 2.2.0.0.0.7710866
2018-01-31 06:37:22 status half-configured kaupackage:amd64 2.2.0.0.0.7707465
```

and

```
dpkg -l
```

shows

```
iFR kaupackage  2.2.0.0.0.7707465  amd64  pkgdescription
```

I am not looking for workaround or solution to recover from this state. This command was working before and suddenly stopped working. So I need to know why.

How can I find out root cause ? Where can I find more logs ? How can I enable more logging ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think dpkg have a verbose option for installing packages... Although, I know there is a dpkg log in `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

I'd rather recommend to uninstall and install new version and or install package from a repository using `apt-get kaupackage`...

Do you see maybe something in syslog or in dpkg.log?

Regards,

Comment: In dpkg.log I see message saying package is half configured

Comment: Have you tried installing the package in other host? Did it help you? could you give me a vote?